# Duplicating Pages error

Tags: magento-1.9

Iam intended to get recent posts in two page one on Homepage other on blog page and I found the code for getting recent pages.The below code is for home page

```
<?php if ($posts = $this->getRecent()): ?>
    <div class="widget-latest">

        <h2><?php echo Mage::helper('blog')->__('RECENT POSTS'); ?></h2>

        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo $post->getAddress(); ?>" ><?php echo $post->getTitle(); ?></a><?php //echo $post->getPostContent(); ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I duplicated this code and saved other file and added this extra line `<?php //echo $post->getPostContent(); ?>`to be visible in blog page.
Now I also found this code is extracting from  a certain Last.php page

```
 protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('aw_blog/widget_post.phtml');
        if ($this->_helper()->getEnabled()) {
            return $this->setData('blog_widget_recent_count', $this->getBlocksCount())->renderView();
        }
    }
```

I also duplicated this code by replacing

`$this->setTemplate('aw_blog/widget_post.phtml');` this code and by pasting duplicated .phtml page name and here my problem occured when I call this page all my sidebar section from my blog page loosing.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: is this the aw-blog extension??

Comment: yes it is aw blog extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Last.php page of Aw-Blog extension make sure you give `AW_Blog_Block_your_duplicate_pagename` in the place of `AW_Blog_Block_Last`

```
class AW_Blog_Block_Last extends AW_Blog_Block_Menu_Sidebar implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('aw_blog/your_duplicate_page.phtml');

        if ($this->_helper()->getEnabled()) {
            return $this->setData('blog_widget_recent_count', $this->getBlocksCount())->renderView();
        }
    }
```

Comment: for example my duplicate last.php name is lasthome so you mean to say i should give in this way `class AW_Blog_Block_Lasthome extends AW_Blog_Block_Menu_Sidebar implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface` ??

Comment: Yes exactly you should extensd the clases to your duplicate page.

Comment: it worked such a small thing I missed thankyou